# Purging numpy.memmap

Tags: python, numpy, mmap, memory-mapped-files, large-data

Given a `numpy.memmap` object created with `mode='r'` (i.e. read-only), is there a way to force it to purge all loaded pages out of physical RAM, without deleting the object itself?

In other words, I'd like the reference to the `memmap` instance to remain valid, but all physical memory that's being used to cache the on-disk data to be uncommitted. Any views onto to the `memmap` array must also remain valid.

I am hoping to use this as a diagnostic tool, to help separate "real" memory requirements of a script from "transient" requirements induced by the use of `memmap`.

I'm using Python 2.7 on RedHat.

Comment: If you're only using this as a diagnostic tool, then you can read those diagnostics more easily other ways.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118307/a-way-to-determine-a-processs-real-memory-usage-i-e-private-dirty-rss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run "pmap SCRIPT-PID", the "real" memory shows as "[ anon ]" blocks, and all memory-mapped files show up with the file name in the last column.

Purging the pages is possible at C level, if you manage to get ahold of the pointer to the beginning of the mapping and call madvise(ptr, length, MADV_DONTNEED) on it, but it's going to be cludgy.