# How to get the max memory usage of a program using psutil in Python

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, memory

I am using the following code to get the max memory usage of the program.

```
    import os, subprocess , psutil
    def mem(cmd):
        try:
            with open('in.txt','r') as infile, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                p=psutil.Popen("./"+cmd,shell=False,stdin=infile,stdout = outfile)
            print p.memory_info()
        except Exception:
             print "Error"
    cmd=raw_input()
    mem(cmd)
```

The problem is sometimes for initial runs of the program the memory usage output is (0,0) but subsequently it displays the correct output. I dont why this happening. For some programs such as the hello world program in c++ the output is `pmem(rss=4096, vms=315392)` which is about 0.3M( I think the output is in bytes ) but running the hello world program in ideone.com gives the output as ~3M. Why is there this disperency?

cmd is the name of the executable.

The output of command `print subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'v', '-p', str(p.pid)])`

`PID TTY      STAT   TIME  MAJFL   TRS   DRS   RSS %MEM COMMAND
16150 pts/16   Z+     0:00      0     0     0     0  0.0 [a.out] <defunct>`

One of my sample C++ program:

```
`int a[1000000];
int main()
{
    return 0;
}`
```

returns pmem(rss=4096, vms=4313088) sometimes and pmem(rss=0,vms=0) sometimes

Comment: Could you reproduce it with a known program such as `["python", "-c", "pass"]`? Are you sure, you haven't suppressed an exception i.e., `Popen()` started successfully?

Comment: unrelated: if `stderr=PIPE` then you should read from `p.stderr` otherwise the process may block forever if it generates enough output on stderr to fill the corresponding OS pipe buffer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian removed stderr.

Comment: What does `print subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'v', '-p', str(p.pid)])` show?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I added exception handling . Sometime the output is (0,0) and there is no exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<defunct>` means that the subprocess is a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) (it is dead but its status has not been read yet by the parent (`p.poll()` or `p.wait()`)). It seems both `psutil` and `ps` shows `RSS` to be zero for such processes.

The result depends on whether the subprocess will exit sooner than `p.memory_info()` is called. It is a race. If you add a delay at the exit in the C++ program then `p.memory_info()` may be called before the subprocess exits and you should get non-zero results.

> The problem is that I can get arbitrary programs to evaluate . The language is also not fixed. Isn't there an elegant solution to this problem?

You might need OS support to save info about the memory usage by a subprocess even after it exits. Or you could run the program using a memory profiler such as `valgrind` and read its results. To collect results:

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif cmd arg1 arg2
```

To see the results, you could use `ms_print`:

```
$ ms_print massif.out.* | less
```

Or GUI [`Massif-Visualizer`](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/sdk/massif-visualizer)

[@mdadm suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22733531/4279) a simpler solution: [`time` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['time', '-f', '%M'] + args, stderr=PIPE)
ru_maxrss = int(p.communicate()[1])
print("Maximum rss %d KB" % ru_maxrss)
```

GNU time uses `wait3()` to populate resource usage info if it is available. It can be called in Python:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(args)
ru = os.wait4(p.pid, 0)[2]
print("Maximum rss %d KB" % ru.ru_maxrss)
```

I've compared the maximum value returned by `psutil.Process.memory_info` (rss) with `ru_maxrss` value returned by `os.wait4` and with the maximum total memory reported by `valgrind --tool=massif`: *they are similar*.

See also:

- [A way to determine a process's “real” memory usage, i.e. private dirty RSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118307/4279)
- [How is memory usage reported in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/48582/3933)
- [Find maximum memory consumed by a process specified at the command-line.](https://gist.github.com/zed/9859060)

Comment: but I got a <defunct> even when pmem(rss=4096, vms=4313088)... Is it due to race conditions because I put the print statement after p.memory_info()

Comment: The subprocess may have already died by the time you called `ps` but it was still alive during `p.memory_info()`

Comment: The problem is that I can get arbitrary programs to evaluate . The language is also not fixed. Isn't there a elegant solution to this problem

Comment: i tried using `/usr/bin/time -v ./a.out<int.txt>out.txt` but still the resident set size is not accurate, it is very low

Comment: I've added `os.wait4()`-based solution. It is similar to your original `resource`-based solution. Have you compared them to `psutil`, `valgrind` results?

Comment: I dont know how to use valgrind now I observed that my psutil results were showing rss=4096 a constant value whenever the there was some non zero output.To calculate the memory I used vms which was actually wrong. Is there anything wrong with my system? To compare memory sizes I am using online compilers such as ideone.com

Comment: I've shown, how to use `valgrind`. I've tried to measure the maximum memory consumed by `python2 -c 'range(10000000)'` and the results reported by `valgrind --tool=massif`, `psutil.Process.memory_info()`, and `ru_maxrss` are similar. I think your system is ok. `ideone.com` probably also uses `ru_maxrss`-based solution.

Comment: @user2179293: To be sure: `p.memory_info()` returns *current* memory usage. Here's [the code I've used to find the maximum memory using `psutil`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9859060)

Comment: Can you check the memory usage of https://ideone.com/KK1rak. I used your program and the output is 4Mb on my system while it is 49Mb on ideone.

Comment: this ["hello world" example](https://ideone.com/806h9P) ideone -- `2292KB`, ru_maxrss -- `4816KB`, psutil.memory_info -- `(352, 4164)` (KB). ideone may use [32bit system](https://ideone.com/g6QNCX), mine is 64bit -- it might explain the difference

Comment: I've tried Python script: [`s = b"a"*(250*(1 << 20))`](https://ideone.com/XZa6Oq) that should show around `250MB` memory. It shows `9440KB` on ideone.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that psutils takes a quick snapshot from the /proc filesystem, as you can see in the [source](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/_pslinux.py).

When you run your hello world example, in some cases it finishes before python gets a chance to read the values from /proc.

Once the process is finished, it effectively no longer consumes any ram.  You can confirm this with an strace.

```
open("/proc/13420/statm", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n", 1024)        = 14
```

If you modify your example to use something like sleep, you'll notice that psutils consistently gives memory usage back.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World.. sleeping!";
  sleep(3);
}
```

Output of your python script...

```
a.out
meminfo(rss=286720, vms=12931072)
```

One simple way to accomplish what you are trying to do, is by using the /usr/bin/time command, which on most platforms will give you the average total memory usage of the process you launch OR use valgrind as J.F Sebastian suggests... whom posted as I was researching and testing my answer ;)

```
Hello World.. sleeping!0.00user 0.00system 0:03.00elapsed 0%CPU     
(0avgtext+0avgdata 1144maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+348minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/time -f %M <command>` will print "Maximum resident set size of the process during  its  lifetime, in Kilobytes"

Comment: Why rss size is so low when I am running the program. My max rss size is 3292KB for a program whose actual memory usage is about 49MB? Is there a problem with my system?