# Check memory per processes and subprocesses

Tags: bash, shell, memory, process, subprocess

I am attempted to create a script that show how much each process and subprocess of mysqld is using. You can see what I have done in my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
#file contains the output of: pstree mysql -a -p |awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/|-        {mysqld},//' >> psadd
filename='psadd'
#total= '0'
echo Start
while read p; do
    memU= cat /proc/$p/smaps |grep -e Private -e Shared |awk '{print $2}' |awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}'
    echo "Process ID:"$p  "Memory Usage:"$memU
total="$((total+memu))"
echo "This is the current running total:" $total
done < $filename
echo "Total=" $total
```

Please if you have any ideas they will be much appreciated.

Comment: related: [How to get the max memory usage of a program using psutil in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22732932/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating a processes memory usage is... [complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35138/67276).  I generally use a proc's RSS -- Resident Set Size -- the amount of memory a process is holding in memory, that isn't shared by other procs.

The following finds the process ID of the MySQL daemon, and uses `ps` to output the RSS value with no header. Lastly it multiplies this by four to get the RSS size in KiB. (Default pagesize is 4 KiB.)

[ps](http://man.cx/?page=ps&do%5Bgo%5D=go) has tons of information -- have fun!

## shell

```
ps -o rss= -p `pidof mysqld` | awk '{print $1*4, "KiB"}'
```

## output

```
7808 KiB
```

Comment: Thank you that does clear a few things up for me.
If you dont mind I am having trouble getting that into my script.
`code`
    #!/bin/bash
    #file contains the output of: pstree mysql -a -p |awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/|-{mysqld},//' >> psadd
    filename='psadd'
    #total= '0'
    echo Start
    while read p; do
        memU=`ps -o rss= -p $p | awk '{print $1*4, "KiB"}'`
        echo "Process ID:"$p  "Memory Usage:"$memU
    #total="$((total+memU))"
    #echo "This is the current running total:" $total
    done < $filename
    #echo "Total=" $total
`code`
Thanks for any help again.

Comment: Ran out of time to edit my comment!
http://pastebin.com/yUbHjU5j

You can see my code at the above pastbin better formated.
ps throws an error, but I thought I was passing the variable correctly. Thanks again good sir.

Comment: Or at least how to do I pass a list of pids to the command you gave.
I tried using the variable $p with no luck.
I tried passing the list /tmp/psadd which has a new pid on each line with no luck as well.

Comment: pstree doesn't list mysqld and sub-processes, it lists sub-*threads*. "Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name in curly braces" http://man.cx/?page=pstree   It's confusing :)

Comment: Doesn't `ps` already give `rss` in `KiB` and not in `pages`? In the [manual](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ps1.html) I can find `resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes). (alias rssize, rsz)`. Also, the key `resident` would give `resident pages` instead of `resident set size` given by key `rss`. I guess this means the above command would give 4 times the memory occupied.

Comment: However if you get it directly from /proc/stat then `rss` would be expressed in number of pages, wherein you need to multiply by page size to get memory used in same unit (as that of the page size)