# How to get all process ids with memory usage greater than

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, ps

I need to get all process ids which have memory usage greater or lower than predifined number. For example get id where memory (rss) usage grater than 10MB and then using this id kill each process. Thanks

Comment: OK! Show what you did so far and what is not working, so we can try to help you. If it is your homework, start by trying to do it ;)

Comment: Hint : Try to get the list of process running

Comment: Use `top` or `ps auxw` or `pgrep` ; perhaps pipe its output to `awk`

Comment: If this is homework, then the teacher is a true BOFH :-))

Comment: Also see [How to see top processes sorted by actual memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802481/608639) and [Check memory per processes and subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25495619/608639), [Script to get user that has process with most memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177409/608639), [A way to determine a process's “real” memory usage, i.e. private dirty RSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118307/608639), etc

Answer (score 1):

This following command will help I think,

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea.  You will certainly kill processes you should not and might render your system damaged in the process.  But anyway, here's what does the trick:

```
ps -eo rss=,pid=,user=,comm= k -rss |
  while read size pid user comm
  do
    [ "$user" = "alfe" ] || continue  # adjust user name here
    if [ "$size" -gt 10000 ]
    then
      echo "kill $pid # $size $user $comm"
    else
      break
    fi
  done
```

You might want to replace the `echo` line by a line using `kill` directly, but as I said, this will probably kill processes you should not kill.

The line with the `continue` is meant to skip all processes which are not of a specific user; I just assumed that; if you intend to run this as `root`, feel free to remove that line.