# Script to get user that has process with most memory usage?

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, sh

How can I write a script that gives an output of the user that has the process with the most memory usage in the system. The script is sh. I tried to use top command as the starting point but it seems it does not work with pipes because it continues running until it is quit.

Comment: Do you want the user ID (uid) or the user _name_?

Comment: `top` is more for an interactive/visual view of what is going on. For use in scripts, you will find `ps` to be more useful.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the *user name* of the process using the most memory, try something like:

```
$ ps axho user --sort -rss | head -1
```

This checks the resident memory size `rss` of the processes.  If you'd rather check the whole virtual size, use `vsz` instead of `rss`.  If you want percentage of resident memory used, use `pmem` (but this could change from moment to moment due to the scheduler, and may not pull out the biggest memory hog).  If you'd rather have the user ID instead of user name, use `uid` instead of `user`.

The `ps` options are:

- `ax` for "all processes" (everybody)
- `h` for "no header" in output
- `o` to specify the output format: `user` (user name)
- `--sort -rss` sort by `rss` (descending order)

The `head -1` strips out all but the first line (which has the largest `rss` since it's in descending order).

It might be useful to get not just the user name, but some more information about the process, like:

```
$ ps axho user,pid,rss --sort -rss | head -1
```

This gives the user name, process ID, and resident memory usage of the top process, all on one line.  You could pull out the values individually in whatever script you use it in.

Comment: > ps axho user --sort -rss | head -1
The term 'head' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (head:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

this works in centos: list most  memory cost process

```
[root@182 ~] # ps aux | sort -k 4 -r | head -n2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      7048  0.2  9.6 8060236 1573612 ?     Ssl  Dec14   8:23 java -Djava.security.e
```

sort -k 4 : sort by the forth column, my pc column4 = %MEM

in other linux/unix, you may find the right column number for memory

Comment: So far, l have been able to get very close by using: ps aux | sort -k 4 -r | head -n2 | tail -n1 . It gives: robot     3024  3.1  4.6 2946368 176980 ?      SLl  04:39   7:13 /opt/google/chrome/chrome

Comment: My interest is to get only the user i.e robot

Comment: ps aux | sort -k 4 -r | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

if you're allowed to use only `top`, this can be a solution:

```sh
top -o VIRT -n 1 | head -8 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

- `top -o VIRT` allows you to override sorting by default column and sort it by column `VIRT`
- `top -n 1` allows you to limit iterations that `top` will make before exiting. We need only one iteration - it's like when you take a photo while recording a video - you saved info at a particular moment
- `| head -8` allows you to output only first 8 lines of previous output/ Why 8? It's because top is displaying a lot of info before displaying the table with processes:
  [we don't need all these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnGBu.png)

```
Tasks: 247 total,   1 running, 245 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5,9 us,  1,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 92,6 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15698,4 total,   7256,4 free,   3087,8 used,   5354,2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  18222,0 total,  18222,0 free,      0,0 used.  11441,1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6249 mneznaev  20   0   46,5g 287484 110232 S   0,0   1,8   5:40.11 code
```

- `| tail -1` allows you to get the last line of previous 8 lines that we got by previous step with `head` and now we have:

```
   6249 mneznaev  20   0   46,5g 290332 110232 S   0,0   1,8   5:40.27 code
```

- `cut -d ' ' -f 5` allows you to separate file by columns, where `-d ' '` is an option that defines space as a separator and `-f 5` allows you to get the 5th column/ Why 5th? That's because there are some spaces before the actual value of PID (before 6249 in my case) and first 3 columns after cut by space are empty. And the 5th column is a username:

```sh
mneznaev@mneznaev-desktop:~$ top -o VIRT -n 1 | head -8 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5
mneznaev
```

That's it. Hope it was helpful