# How to display processes that are using memory in an given range

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command

How can I display processes that are using memory between an given interval in terminal? For exemple: processes that are using between 50 and 100 MB of Memory.

I tried:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $4}' | sort
```

but this only displays the memory for every process sorted and not in an interval.

Comment: Also see [How to see top processes sorted by actual memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802481/608639) and [Check memory per processes and subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25495619/608639), [How to get all process ids with memory usage greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26862748/608639), [Script to get user that has process with most memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177409/608639), [A way to determine a process's “real” memory usage, i.e. private dirty RSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118307/608639), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list processes as expected. Remember that ps shows memory size in kilobytes.

```
ps -u 1000 -o pid,user,stime,rss \
  | awk '{if($4 > 50000 && $4 < 100000){ print $0 }}' \
  | sort -n -k 4,4
```

Command output:

```
 3407 luis.mu+ 10:30 51824
 3523 luis.mu+ 10:30 66108
 3410 luis.mu+ 10:30 71060
 3595 luis.mu+ 10:30 74340
 3609 luis.mu+ 10:30 77772
18550 luis.mu+ 16:47 93616
```

In that case it's showing only 4 fields for user id 1000. To show all processes use

```
ps -e -o pid,user,stime,rss
```

From the `ps(3)` man page under `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`:

> rss
>   resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (inkiloBytes)

If you want to show more fields, check the man page and add fields to `-o` option.

Comment: when I type `ps aux` the memory used by every proccess is displayed in procentage (%) and not if Kilobyts as you said. So I tried:

`ps aux -u | awk '{if($4 >= 0.05 && $4 <= 0.1){ print $0 }}'`

and it worked. But how can I display the memory in kilobytes as you said?

Comment: Added clarification to the answer, hope it helps. Try the ps command alone to check the output.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex testing, including comparison, inequality, and numerical tests, awk is very useful:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $4}' | sort | awk '$1 >= 1 && $1 <=2'| cat
```

Here I am checking the memory usage between 1MB and 2MB using `awk` and printing them using `cat`.