# Accessing stdout when using "time" in python subproces

Tags: python, shell, time, stdout, benchmarking

I have been doing some manual benchmark tests in my shell using the `time` command. I would like to scale my benchmarks by writing a python script that both automates the tests and affords me access to the time data so that I can record it in the format of my choosing (likely a csv). I see there is the `timeit` module, but that seems like it is more for benchmarking python code, where what I am trying to benchmark here are programs run in the command line.

This is what I have been doing manually:

```
time program -aflag -anotherflag
```

My initial attempt to implement this in a script looks like:

```
cmnd = ['time', 'program', 'aflag', 'anotherflag']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate
print out
print err
```

I can access the output of `time` just fine – this is delivered to stderr, however I am not getting `program`'s output as expected in stdout. If I remove `time` from `cmnd` and change `shell=False` to True, I then get the program's output in stdout – however obviously not `time`'s output, which is the whole point.

```
cmnd = ['program', 'aflag', 'anotherflag']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate
print out
print err
```

If I add `time` back to cmnd with `shell=True`, I get time's output but `program` doesn't actually run.

How can I get both working?

Comment: Please copy-paste an **actuall** short, standalone program that demonstrates your error. Please do not just type it in, but test it, run it, and copy-paste it. Thanks. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the `time` command in shell doesn't show the result !! it just show the time `real` ,`os`,`user` !

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors in your test program, and replacing your `cmnd` with `cmnd = ['time', 'ls', '-s', '-h']`, I get the correct results in both `out` and `err`. [This link](http://ideone.com/ALUs52) contains my program.

Comment: so whats your program ? is it a python code ? or ... ?

Comment: @Kasra: It's even worse than that; the program `/usr/bin/time` and the shell builtins named `time` in different shells are all different in what they do with the program's output and/or error, which makes it very confusing for novices to write code around the command…

Comment: note: it is an error to use `shell=True` and a list argument in this  case (like in most cases). 'program' doesn't see its arguments in this case. Either use `shell=False` or pass the shell command as a string.

Comment: you could [use `ru = os.wait4(p.pid, 0)` + `resource` module to get the data without `/usr/bin/time` command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22733285/4279). There is [`psutil.Process(p.pid)` that allows to get process info in a portable manner](https://gist.github.com/zed/9859060).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You don't need `os.wait` for anything; `p.communicate()` (if you remember the parens) will take care of the waiting for you.

Comment: @abarnert: os.wait4() is used to get the resource usage info. Follow the links to see the code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But it's not necessary. `p.communicate()` waits for the process (with `waitpid` on *nix), `resource.getrusage` gets the resource information. If you want to distinguish between separate child processes, then you need something more complicated; if you just have one, do it the easy way.

Comment: @abarnert: you've answered it yourself: `os.wait4()` allows you to pass child's pid explicitly to distinguish between several child processes.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But it makes things significantly more complicated. You can't call `os.wait4` and also call `p.communicate`, so you have to… well, see my edited answer. If you don't need the extra complexity, don't do it.

Comment: it could be done much simpler e.g., redirect to a temporary file if you need the output (unrelated to resource usage).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Redirecting to a temporary file and then reading that file is not simpler than just calling `resource.rusage`.

Comment: It *is* simpler than subclassing Popen and overwriting private methods like in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to get this to work, why not use the functionality built into Python in the [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) module?

```
import resource
import subprocess

cmd = ['program', 'aflag', 'anotherflag']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
usage = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
print out
print err
print usage.ru_utime, usage.ru_stime, usage.ru_utime+usage.ru_stime
```

---

If you need to distinguish different child processes running simultaneously, `getrusage` isn't obviously not sufficient. In that case, you need to use [`wait4`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait4) or similar to get per-process resource usage. This makes your use of `Popen` more complicated. What you'd probably want to do for this case is subclass or fork the `subprocess` code (but make sure to use [`subprocess32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32) backport if you're on 3.1 or earlier to avoid the bugs in `communicate`—and so that the class actually has the method you want to hook…) and change [the `_try_wait` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/subprocess.py#l1510) to use `wait4` instead of `waitpid` and stash the extra results in, e.g., `self.rusage` so you can access it later.

I think something like this would work:

```
import subprocess32

class Popen(subprocess32.Popen):
    def _try_wait(self, wait_flags):
        """All callers to this function MUST hold self._waitpid_lock."""
        try:
            (pid, sts, rusage) = _eintr_retry_call(os.wait4, self.pid, wait_flags)
            if pid == self.pid:
                self.rusage = rusage
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECHILD:
                raise
            pid = self.pid
            sts = 0
        return (pid, sts)

cmd = ['program', 'aflag', 'anotherflag']
p = Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess32.PIPE, stderr=subprocess32.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
print err
try:
    usage = p.rusage
except AttributeError:
    print 'Child died before we could wait on it, no way to get rusage'        
else:
    print usage.ru_utime, usage.ru_stime, usage.ru_utime+usage.ru_stime
```